# Create onboard screen in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have created onboard viewcontroller using UICollectionView
[image: This is screen]

but when I swipe, the picture goes out of the iphone, I want the picture to clip inside the phone and show other image. How can i achieve that?

Comment: I have got a code on GitHub that does a similar job. 
Here's the link: https://github.com/karanthakakr04/Walkthrough-Demo.git
I hope it serves your need. Also there's this reference tutorial if someone needs it: https://youtu.be/tNCsQe5vfRk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the frame of the collection view fit the the screen of the phone image.

For example if the upper left corner of the screen of your phone image is located at x:20, y: 40 and the screen of your phone image is 160x300 big, then the following should be your collection views frame:

```
collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 40, width: 160, height: 300)
```

If you are using AutoLayout, make sure that the edges of your collection view are lined up with the edges of your phone images screen.